# For loop not incrementing or while loop not failing test

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, collatz

I have this section of code that's supposed to find the Collatz sequence of all integers in a given range, defined by user input. The problem is that in the `for` loop, `current_number` never gets incremented, or in the inner `while` loop, `current_number != 1` never fails. What am I missing?

```
while (lower != 0 && upper != 0) {
    cout << "Lower bound (integer): ";
    cin >> lower;
    cout << "Upper bound (integer): ";
    cin >> upper;
    if (lower == 0 || upper == 0)
        return 0;
    for (current_number = lower; current_number <= upper;
        ++current_number) {
            //cout << current_number << endl;
            counter = 0;
            sequence = sequence + to_string(current_number) + ", ";
            while (current_number != 1) {
                if (current_number % 2 == 0) {
                    current_number = current_number / 2;
                    sequence = sequence + to_string(current_number) + ", ";
                }
                else {
                    current_number = current_number * 3 + 1;
                    sequence = sequence + to_string(current_number) + ", ";
                }
                cout << current_number << endl;
                ++counter;
            }
            //if (counter > longest) {
            //  longest = counter;
            //  the_longest_seed = current_number;
            //}
    }
    cout << sequence << endl;

}
```

Comment: What type are `lower`, `upper`, `current_number`, `counter`, and `sequence` declared as? And can we safely assume that `to_string` returns a `char` array?

Comment: Do you see any progress (prints) when you run? What were the inputs?

Comment: I forgot to say that all variables are `int`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the other error, you are also using `current_number` to iterate over the input-range and you're changing it to output your Collatz sequence.  You should change a copy of `current_number`.

Answer (score 7):

`current_number % 2 == 0` is true for all `current_number = 0, 2, 4, 6, ...`.

When this happens, you set `current_number` to be `current_number / 2`.. So when `current_number` is 2, you're setting it to 1, then you increment it (`++current_number`), then it's 2 again (`!= 1`), so you'll enter the `while` loop, then because `2 % 2 = 0` you'll set it to 1 again.. And so on.. :_(

Tip for life: Debug your code, it'll save time, efforts and sometimes money too.

Comment: How do you mean to debug? I had tried putting some output statements in, but that wasn't helping me figure out where things went south. If you mean debug using the IDE (MSVC 2013 RC in my case), then I don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning never-failing loop. If current_number != 1 and it is not 2 (if it is, the other guy has answered), it goes into the while loop and never ends, because...

Let's say it is 3:

3 % 2 != 0, so it becomes 10,

10 % 2 == 0, so it becomes 5,

5 %2 != 0, so it becomes 16

...

Never fails.